# How to enumerate connected USB storage devices Ubuntu Java

Tags: java, ubuntu-14.04, usb-drive

I have an application, mostly in Java' that controls an airborne infrared camera via a webpage GUI (served by the Ubuntu machine) which starts running automatically when the computer is powered up and towards the end of the boot. The application runs as a user, not root, even though the user is not logged in.

After a great many images are collected the data need to be archived by using rsync to a folder on the operator's USB drive.  I need to have the USB drive mounted and know its name tag. The computer is headless and the operator, who is on the aircraft, cannot be expected to know Linux in any case.

On an Ubuntu I see that logged in and running the xfce4 GUI, and only then, the drives are listed in /media/user-name/drive-tag  (I note that /media/username is owned by root but the folder named for the drive is owned by the user.) and are shown in /etc/mtab :

```
/dev/sdd1 /media/programmer/DATA-02-2TB vfat rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1001,gid=1001,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks2 0 0
```

How can I, through Java or through a combination of Java and bash, detect and mount a USB storage device?

If that's not possible do I need to ask the user, through the GUI, to enter the device tag or name, e.g., 'DATA-02-2TB' and then create the mount point and mount the USB drive via a script using the information above?

Comment: I don't know, how to do it in pure java right now. I'll need to read more about that. Nevertheless on Ubuntu you can simply call `lsusb` command in terminal. It will display information about USB ports and devices connected to them. You can use `-t` parameter to see ports in a tree hierarchy or `-v` parameter to see detailed information about ports and connected devices. It doesn't answer your whole question, but it may be starting point for solving the problem.

Comment: Thanks, assuming that Bus 004 is always bound with the two ports then what I get is that something made by "LaCie, Ltd" (in this case) is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install usbmount, a Ubuntu tool.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install usbmount
```

Then edit the /etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf file:

```
sudo sed -i 's/MOUNTOPTIONS="/MOUNTOPTIONS="user,umask=000,/' /etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf
```

These steps are described at [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/414120/). Note that only a subset of drive formats is supported including the ubiquitous VFAT.

With this in place USB external drives and thumb drives will mount in /media as /media/usb0 through /media/usb7 and will be listed in /etc/mtab.

```
/dev/sdc1 /media/usb0 vfat rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,sync,noatime,nodiratime,umask=000 0 0
```

I've tested this on my 14.04 machine.  Now if I could only get the drive label.

Edit: The **sync** option does not work well with flash drives. Read the /etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf file for details and remove "sync" from the appropriate line in that file.  A full backup made with **sync** option ran for over an hour before I cancelled it but took only about 5 minutes with **sync**  removed.  Note the comment about using **pumount** to unmount the non-synched drive.

```
public static ArrayList<String> usbDriveList() throws FileNotFoundException {

    final String MTB_ADDRESS = "/etc/mtab";
    final String TARGET = "^/media/usb[0-7]$"; // REGEX

    final File file = new File(MTB_ADDRESS);
    final ArrayList<String> driveList = new ArrayList<String>();

    try (Scanner in = new Scanner(file)) {
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            final String[] splitLine = in.nextLine().split(" ");
            if (splitLine[1].matches(TARGET)) {
                driveList.add(splitLine[1]); // got it!
            }
        }
    } catch (final FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
    }

    return driveList;
}
```